# Adding OpenCV libraries in SGX-Enclave Project

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2015, face-detection, sgx, enclave

I am trying to add OpenCV in my enclave project. I can run the OpenCV project as a standalone win32 console application in visual studio 2015. But when I started doing that in my enclave project I am getting errors. I tried to add the following libraries from opencv in enclave project:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/face.hpp>
#include "drawLandmarks.hpp"
```

But I am getting tons of error. I also need to include windows.h file in my project. Are those libraries are allowed to include in the enclave project?

I followed the following steps while adding opencv static library in the project:-

1. Generated the OpenCV static library using CMake,
2. Added the following values in the inlucde directories :-

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\IntelSGXSDK\include
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\IntelSGXSDK\include\libc++
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\IntelSGXSDK\include\tlibc
   C:\Users\fs5ve\Downloads\Opencv-static\static\opencv\include
   C:\Users\fs5ve\Downloads\Opencv-static\static\opencv\build-32-extra\install\include
   C:\Users\fs5ve\Downloads\Opencv-static\static\opencv\build-32-extra\install\include\opencv
   C:\Users\fs5ve\Downloads\Opencv-static\static\opencv\build-32-extra\install\include\opencv2
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include
   %(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
3. Added the following value in additional library directories:-

   $(SGXSDKInstallPath)bin\$(Platform)\Debug;C:\Users\fs5ve\Downloads\Opencv-static\static\opencv\build-32-extra\install\x86\vc14\staticlib
4. Added the following values in the addtional dependecies :-

   sgx_trts_sim.lib
   sgx_tstdc.lib
   sgx_tservice_sim.lib
   sgx_tcrypto.lib
   sgx_tcxx.lib
   sgx_urts_sim.lib
   sgx_uae_service_sim.lib
   opencv_calib3d400d.lib
   opencv_core400d.lib
   opencv_highgui400d.lib
   opencv_face400d.lib
   opencv_features2d400d.lib
   opencv_flann400d.lib
   opencv_imgcodecs400d.lib
   opencv_imgproc400d.lib
   opencv_ml400d.lib
   opencv_objdetect400d.lib
   opencv_photo400d.lib
   opencv_shape400d.lib
   opencv_stitching400d.lib
   opencv_superres400d.lib
   opencv_video400d.lib
   opencv_videoio400d.lib
   opencv_videostab400d.lib

I am getting the following error:-
Cannot open include file: 'emmintrin.h': No such file or directory

I have added "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include"  in the Include directories. But after that I am getting the following error:-
Cannot open include file: 'malloc.h': No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that OpenCV has lots and lots of dependencies and instructions that simply are not available while in the Enclave (e.g. Intel SSE or standard pthreading).

So a direct linking is not possible, but you could always port it - although I must advise it's quite a massive job, so you must consider whether or not it's worth.